# Spring @transactional not rollingback

Tags: java, spring, transactional

As part of a web app i am trying to build a registration process. after validating the process there are three sql statments to be performed. If any should fail then they should all be rolled back. However If i purposefully write the 3rd sql to fail (use a table name that doesnt exist). I see exception being thrown but the 1st and 2nd swl statments are not rolled back.

Can someone advise me on how this should be done.

from my application-context.xml

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.doyleisgod.golf.database.JdbcUserDao">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="registration" class="com.doyleisgod.golf.services.Registration"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
```

My registration service class

```
public class Registration implements IRegistration {
@Autowired JdbcUserDao userDAO;

@Override
@Transactional (rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public boolean registerUser(Object command) {
    return userDAO.registerUser(command);
}
}
```

my userDAO registration method

```
    public boolean registerUser(Object command)  {
    try {
        setUserCommand(command);
        sql = "INSERT INTO users (USERNAME,PASSWORD, ENABLED)VALUES ('"+username+"', '"+EncryptedPassword+"', TRUE);";
        getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO user_roles (USERNAME,AUTHORITY)VALUES ('"+username+"', 'ROLE_USER');";
        getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO users_details (USERNAME,FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS, HANDICAP)VALUES ('"+username+"', '"+firstname+"', '"+lastname+"', '"+email+"', '"+handicap+"');";
        getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(sql);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}
```

Exampl of exception being thrown

```
    15-Feb-2012 21:13:48 org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO users_details (USERNAME,FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS, HANDICAP)VALUES ('d', 'd', 'd', 'd', '0');]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'golf.users_details' doesn't exist
```

Can someone tell me what i have missed. Why when the 3rd sql statment fails do the other 2 transactions not get rolled back?

Comment: how is the connection getting set up?  does it have autocommit turned on?

Comment: ERm, My honest answer is I am not sure john. I started this little project based on a spring example project. Is there somewhere I can check this?

Comment: BTW: do not use this code in production, it enables SQL Injection!!

Comment: oh....Just now i am building and running on local host with tomcat and mysql but i had planned on once i had a working example to host it somewhere. I wasnt aware this would be a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are catching the exception in your DAO, it is not thrown to the TransactionManager.

Comment: So the DAO should throw the error back to the registration service?

Comment: Ok so now my DAO is throwing exceptions back. In the service layer if i rap the call to the DAO in a try catch i can see the excpetion being caught in the service layer. but still sql 1 and 2 are not rolled back even though sql 3 caused an exception. Have i still missed something out?

Comment: No... you can not catch the exception there either... let the TransactionManager catch it.  If you need to handle it, throw it outside of your Transactional annotated method.

Comment: So where is transaction manager fitting in this picture. i have like this registrtionController > resgistration service (wher @transactional is applied to the method) > userDAO excpetion occurs in sql 3 inside uersDAO called method. userDAO method is throwing exception back to registartion service. Either i have to try catch it here or throw error up to registration controller or wise i dont have valid code.

So how should i implement so that transaction manager is catching the exception?

Comment: The TransactionManager runs around the @Transactional annotated method.  If you catch and swallow, it will never see it to rollback.

Comment: Yup I see now. I have set the @ Transactional annotated method to throw the error up to the registration controller which called the registration service. Now when sql 3 fails sql 1 and 2 are rolled back. Thanks for the time and patience with me aweigold. One last question is there some where that suggest best practice for this. I.E which layer @transactional should occur in. where exception hadling should best be performed?

Comment: I prefer to use @Transaction in my service layers.

Comment: can you show the final code sample in your answer? thanks